# Camera Bandwidth Calculation

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, video-streaming, signal-processing

I'd like to calculate camera bandwith. Main question: "How can transmit GigE more than 1 Gbit/s data ?"

----- Camera specs --------

- Resolution (HxV) :2590 px x 1942 px
- Frame Rate : 14 fps
- Mono/Color : Color
- Interface : GigE
- Pixel Bit Depth : 12 bits

---- Bandwith calculation ---

- bit/s = Resolution x ChannelSize(Color) x fps x BitDepth
- bit/s = 2590 x 1942 x 3 x 14 x 12
- bit/s = 2.535.009.120
- Gbit/s = 2.3609

Where am I wrong?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the data from the camera is compressed already or the pixels are laid out in a [Bayer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter) so there's only 12 bits per pixel, not 36.

Comment: Same answer came from manufacturer: "Bayer Pattern"